# How to access S4 methods that are not exported

Tags: r, r-s4

Is there a way to access S4 methods that are not exported? I am working on a package that uses S3 classes. I have a class called `foo`. For `foo` I define a new plot method:

```
plot.foo <- function(x, ...) {
   # some code
   plot(x)  # this should be the plot method of an other S4 package
}
```

In my particular case I would like to call the `plot` method from the `raster` package, which seems not be exported.

Comment: This seems like an oversight on the part of the raster author; contact them (`packageMaintainer('raster")`) and suggest adding exportMethods('plot') to their NAMESPACE file. As written, the package adds the method to the S4 generic created by the sp package, so `sp::plot(x)` in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been exported in the development version of raster (available here: http://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=294) and it should be available in the next release in CRAN.